# curl shows installed in phpinfo, but still get undefined function: curl_init

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, installation

Summary: curl is installed, but I still receive this error attempting to use it:

```
[Mon Nov 14 16:39:05 2011] [error] [client 75.145.113.155] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /.../htdocs/system/application/libraries/paypal/Paypal_pro.php on line 619, referer: http://example.com/buy/checkout
```

from phpinfo:

```
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
```

I've confirmed both /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini and /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/curl.so actually do exist.

Here is the content of curl.ini:

```
extension=curl.so
```

When I view the phpinfo file I created, it shows a section for curl, but the features entry there is blank.  Is that normal?  If not, what would cause that?  I'm using bunut and installed curl with the following command as root:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

It worked with no error.  I've restarted apache a few times with no effect.  I've done this a variety of times on other systems, both Ubunut and RedHat without difficulty, so I have no idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: Are you running this through CLI or through the web server?

Comment: If curl was enabled, then you'd get an entire block of curl data, including "curl: enabled" in the phpinfo() output

Comment: check the Apache error log, as Marc B says, you should see a lot more than merely parsing the curl.ini

Comment: Here's the full curl block: `cURL support: enabled; cURL Information: 7.19.7; Age: 3; Features: [nothing here]; AsynchDNS: No; Debug: No; GSS-Negotiate: Yes; IDN: Yes; IPv6: Yes; Largefile: Yes; NTLM: Yes; SPNEGO: No; SSL: Yes; SSPI: No; krb4: No; libz: Yes; CharConv: No; Protocols: tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps; Host: i486-pc-linux-gnu; SSL Version: OpenSSL/0.9.8k; ZLib Version: 1.2.3.3`

Comment: BTW, this is via the web server as is the phpinfo (so I know it's not a cli vs apache issue)..